# Delete records in a table Every time you UPDATE

Tags: sql-server

There are three tables

```
Table 1 - 1 Review  details record inserted
Table 2 - 2 Services  records for each Review inserted
Table 3 - 2 Medical details records for each service inserted
```

When the update happens below is the updated data from the XML

```
Table 1 - 1  Review record 
Table 2 - 1 Service record for the review
Table 3 - 2 Medical record for the service
```

In this update scenario, I delete the service and medical records that is Table2 and Table3 records and insert the updated records.

If I keep doing the same will the Identity column limit in Table2 and Table3 exceed?

Note: All the details are incoming in form of XML we do not have a specific ServieID or MedicalCodeID  in the XML.

Comment: I'm sorry but the question is unclear to me, and the formatting does not help. Please improve formatting, and give a better explanation of your problem. Adding code snippets that illustrate your problem will also certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

The only question I read was:

> If i keep doing the same will the Identity column limit in Table2 and Table3 exceed ?

Answer: It depends but we do not know due to the lack of detail.

It depends on the identity columns type, the number of records being deleted, and the frequency you are executing the delete.

Example 1: If the identity column was of type `smallint` (max value of 32,767) and you deleted 1 record every day then you would not run out of values for almost 90 years.

Example 2: If you were using the type `bigint` (max value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) then you could delete millions of records each day and still not have to worry about ever running out.

Answer (score 1):

The identity is automatically incremented each time you insert a record. So even if you delete the record later, Identity won't be automatically re-seeded. Instead, you can do it manually.

Even if your insert failed due to some data related issues the identity will be incremented.

Suppose I'm inserting the records into a table having the next value for the identity column 5. So the next value will be 5 for the column. Suppose my data got truncated on the first attempt, I fixed the issue and re-inserted the data, then the next value will be 6 (even if there is no record for value 5)

It will be incremented until it reaches the Limit as the data type permits